# Rails 4, simple_form, devise - Associations not written to the database

Tags: devise, associations, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a basic setup of Rails 4, and Simple_form gem.
I am using simple association to User model, which is actually using Devise gem. When I try to save the User association to "tables_users" db table, it succeeds (respectively this form submits without any errors), but no data is written to the actual database.

Here is the code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @table do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :active %>
  <%= f.association :users %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Models:

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tables
end
```

Answer (score 4):

you must add :user_ids=>[] to the params whitelist in controller

https://coderwall.com/p/_1oejq